# Show images in jquery UI autocomplete in Rails 3.2.11

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete for users.

Here's my code snippet:

```
$("input.autocomplete_user").autocomplete(
{
    // Autocomplete Source: Category json
    source: <%= raw User.select("distinct username as value, user_id as ID").where("username ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").joins(:roles).all(conditions:{roles:{name: 'Creator'}}).to_json %>,
    minLength: 0,
    select: function (event, data) {
        $(this).autocomplete('disable');
        $("input.autocomplete_user_id").attr('value', data.item.id);
        var opval = $("input.autocomplete_user_id").val();
    }

})
```

I would like to show uses' photos as well. Just like this: http://d.pr/i/mfJQ

Do you have any idea(s) for this? Any workarounds will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Actually, I tried this one but didn't work.

```
$("input.autocomplete_user").autocomplete(
{
    // Autocomplete Source: Category json
    source: <%= raw User.select("distinct username as value, user_id as ID, photo_url as foto").where("username ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").joins(:roles).all(conditions:{roles:{name: 'Creator'}}).to_json %>,
    minLength: 0,
    select: function (event, data) {
        $(this).autocomplete('disable');
        $("input.autocomplete_user_id").attr('value', data.item.id);
        var opval = $("input.autocomplete_user_id").val();
    }

})
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul,item){
   return $("<li></li>")
  .data("item.autocomplete",item)
  .append("<a>"+"<img src='" + item.foto +"'>"  + item.first_name + " " + item.last_name + "<br>" + item.username  +  "</a>" )
  .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: did you look at http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: Nope. Because I'm using jquery autocomplete.

Comment: did you get an error?

Comment: No errors even in firebug. Just can't open the specific page where autocomplete exists.

Comment: Are you sure your data is OK? I'm getting the picture for same code with my data.

Comment: I think you get the data as: `"[{\"user\":{:id...}},{\"user\":{:id...}}`, it's not the format you need...

Comment: Thanks I solved it already. Just removed the `;` at the closing parentheses in here `.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append("<a>" +"<img src='" + item.foto + "'>" + item.label + "</a>")
        .appendTo( ul );
    }`

Comment: Great!. notice: you don't need the `+` at `"<a>"+"<img src='"`, just do `"<a><img src='"`